# Как вывести в консоль строку с атрибутами с помощью библиотеки ncurses?

Tags: c++, консоль, ncurses

Как вывести в консоль строку с атрибутами с помощью библиотеки ncurses ?
В следующем коде, я вывожу сообщение в центр экрана, как добавить атрибуты(подчеркивание сообщение, мигание, цвет) к этому сообщению?

```
#include "ncurses.h"
#include "string.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char *mesg = "Just a string";

    //Количество строк и столбцов на экране терминала
    int row, col;

    initscr();

    //Получаем максимально возможное количество строк и столбцов для окна stdscr и записываем эти данные в row и col
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);

    //Выводим сообщение в центре окна stdscr
    mvwprintw(stdscr, row / 2, (col - strlen(mesg)) / 2, "%s" , mesg);
    addch('.' | A_BLINK);
    addch('.' | A_BLINK);
    addch('.' | A_BLINK);

    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте макросы `attron` и `attroff`, которые, соответственно, включают и выключают атрибуты.

```c
attron(COLOR_PAIR(my_color_pair));
mvaddch(y, x, `i`);
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(my_color_pair));
```